# Error in rmOutliers function of highfrequency package in R

Tags: r

The code uses inbuilt `dataset(sample_qdata)` of the package highfrequency and is as below:

Ex:
Consider you have raw quote data for 1 stock for 1 day

```
data("sample_qdata")
head(sample_qdata)
rmoutlier<-rmOutliers(sample_qdata,maxi=10,window=50,type="advanced")
head(rmoutlier)
```

The error that is coming:

> rmoutlier<-rmOutliers(sample_qdata,maxi=10,window=50,type="advanced")
>   Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :

Comment: show a dput of your data

Comment: @erasmortg..1199462356, 1199462357, 1199462358, 1199462359, 1199462360, 1199462361, 
1199462362, 1199462363, 1199462364, 1199462365, 1199462366, 1199462368, 
1199462369, 1199462370, 1199462371, 1199462373, 1199462376, 1199462377, 
1199462379, 1199462385, 1199462386, 1199462388, 1199462389, 1199462390, 
1199462391, 1199462393, 1199462394, 1199462395), .Dim = c(7706L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SYMBOL", "EX", "BID", "BIDSIZ", 
"OFR", "OFRSIZ", "MODE")))

Comment: could you edit your post with the dput? that way you can not only paste a longer output, but also makes it easier for everybody else to have a reproducible set to play with

Comment: 1199462349, 1199462350, 1199462351, 1199462352, 1199462354, 1199462355, 
1199462356, 1199462357, 1199462358, 1199462359, 1199462360, 1199462361, 
1199462362, 1199462363, 1199462364, 1199462365, 1199462366, 1199462368, 
1199462369, 1199462370, 1199462371, 1199462373, 1199462376, 1199462377, 
1199462379, 1199462385, 1199462386, 1199462388, 1199462389, 1199462390, 
1199462391, 1199462393, 1199462394, 1199462395), .Dim = c(7706L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SYMBOL", "EX", "BID", "BIDSIZ", "OFR", "OFRSIZ", "MODE")))
@erasmortg